# PHP extensions on MAMP 3.5

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I have installed MAMP 3.5 with Apache 2.4.16 on Yosemite 10.10.5 and have run into some obstacles that I find hard to solve.

The first issue was that virtual host settings have changed in Apache but that I managed to fix.

The remaining problem is with extensions. I use gettext in an application and it can not be found.

php -v says PHP 5.6.10 (cli)
phpinfo() says PHP 5.5.27
php --ini says /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini

The php.ini path seems to be correct although phpinfo() says that extension_dir is /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212

This seems very strange to me? The gettext extension is not in this directory but is found along with all other relevant extensions in the directory listed in the php.ini file for PHP 5.6.10 which is the one that should be used...

Any ideas what has gone wrong and how I can make PHP use the correct ini file?

Answer (score 2):

CLI uses the installed version of OSX, MAMP uses it's own version.

The easiest way to use same version for both is to add the MAMP version first in your path in ~/.bash_profile.

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/:~/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

of course you need to replace the php7.0.0 part with the version you want to use.
Quit your terminal app and reopen it, and try php -v again.

Comment: Thanks, had already done that but with no luck. The built-in apache seemed to be running with its own php and I couldn't find any way of getting back to using the right one again.... Removed MAMP and re-installed it, now everything seems fine again. Have no clue why this happened though.